# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in a function of Python

Tags: python, function, append, runtime-error, pycharm

I have my nested "final" function to save a text file with append mode. When i execute selection in console mode (with PyCharm) i get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2721, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-62-9c259f95cff2>", line 1, in <module>
    f.write(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2721, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-63-f015ac76386b>", line 12, in <module>
    f.write(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

my function is the following.

```
def segmentation_accuracy(reference, segmented, output, method="ke", threshold=0.1, sep="space", header=True):
    if not check_suffix(reference) or not check_suffix(segmented):
        raise ValueError('the input files need to be ESRI shapefile (*.shp)')
    ref_shp = ogr.Open(os.path.abspath(reference))
    if ref_shp is None:
        raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % reference)
    seg_shp = ogr.Open(os.path.abspath(segmented))
    if seg_shp is None:
        raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % segmented)
    if method == "ke" or method == "pu":
        if threshold is None:
            raise AccuracyException("threshold need to be set with a value between 0.0 and 1.0")
    ref_layer = ref_shp.GetLayer()
    ref_layer_num = ref_layer.GetFeatureCount()
    seg_layer = seg_shp.GetLayer()
    seg_layer_num = seg_layer.GetFeatureCount()
    if ref_layer.GetGeomType() != 3:
        raise ValueError("s% is not a single-part polygons" % (os.path.split(reference)[1]))
    if ref_layer.GetGeomType() != 3:
        raise ValueError("s% is not a single-part polygons" % (os.path.split(segmented)[1]))
    # get shapely polygons
    ref_list = polygon_list(ref_layer)
    seg_list = polygon_list(seg_layer)
    # create text file
    ref_path = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(reference))[0]
    filename = set_outputfile(output, path=ref_path)
    with open(filename, "a") as f:
        if header is True:
            line = ["FID", "centroidX", "centroidY", "area", "perimeter", "segments", "ra_or", "ra_os", "over_seg", \
                    "under_seg", "over_merge", "under_merge", "sim_size", "sim_size_std", "AFI", "qr", "seg_error", \
                    "d_sr", "d_max", "rp_sr"]
            line = sepType[sep].join([str(e) for e in line])+ "\n"
            f.write(line)
        for FID, ref in enumerate(ref_list):
            print FID
            seg_overlap = list()
            for seg in seg_list:
                if ref.intersects(seg):
                    if threshold_type[method](ref, seg, threshold):
                        seg_overlap.append(seg)
            if len(seg_overlap) != 0:
                accuracy = Accuracy(ref, seg_overlap)
                line = [FID] + accuracy.data
                line = sepType[sep].join([str(e) for e in line])+ "\n"
                f.write(line)
            else:
                accuracy = Accuracy(ref)
                line = [FID] + accuracy.data
                line = sepType[sep].join([str(e) for e in line])+ "\n"
                f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related with the line

```
line = ["FID", "centroidX", "centroidY", "area", "perimeter", "segments", "ra_or", "ra_os", "over_seg", \
                    "under_seg", "over_merge", "under_merge", "sim_size", "sim_size_std", "AFI", "qr", "seg_error", \
                    "d_sr", "d_max", "rp_sr"]
```

pycharm prefer the following form

```
line = (["FID", "centroidX", "centroidY", "area", "perimeter", "segments", "ra_or", "ra_os", "over_seg", 
"under_seg", "over_merge", "under_merge", "sim_size", "sim_size_std", "AFI", "qr", "seg_error", 
"d_sr", "d_max", "rp_sr"])
```

[image]